# Changing the background colour of a given row in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I need to change the background color of a given row in a table based on a value of a model (boolean) property which is used in the @Html.CheckBox.  The model is updated with the new checkbox value in the PostExampleCompleted action method.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item name</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Complete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="FooRow">
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>@Model.FooComments</td>
            <td>@Model.FooUserName</td>
            <td>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostFooCompleted", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "ShowProcessingMsg", OnComplete = "HideProcessingMsg" })) 
                {
                    @Html.CheckBox("FooItemComplete", Model.FooComplete, new { onClick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();" })
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="WidgetRow">
            <td>Widget</td>
            <td>@Model.WidgetComments</td>
            <td>@Model.WidgetUserName</td>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostWidgetCompleted", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "ShowProcessingMsg", OnComplete = "HideProcessingMsg" })) 
                {
                    @Html.CheckBox("WidgetItemComplete", Model.WidgetComplete, new { onClick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();" })
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?  Code examples would be appreciated :).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, given that I've understood what you're trying to do correctly.

First here's a css class which I've used to colour a row if a checkbox is checked.

```
.redBackground
{
    background-color: Red;
}
```

Next, here is some JQuery code to colour the row where the check-box resides if it is checked. I've also added a 'change' handler to each check-box so if any of them are updated, the row colour is updated appropriately (I've just used red for a row where a check-box is checked and no colour where a check-box is not checked).

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {

                var checkbox = $(this);

                // if the checkbox is already checked, colour its row
                CheckStatus(checkbox);

                //Every time a check-box status changes we 
                //want to re-evaluate the row colour
                checkbox.change(function () {
                    CheckStatus(checkbox);
                });

            });

            //Method which checks if the check-box is checked. If it's checked
            //the row is given the 'redBackground' class, otherwise it is taken away
            function CheckStatus(checkbox) {
                if (checkbox.attr('checked') == 'checked') {
                    checkbox.parent().parent().addClass('redBackground');
                }
                else {
                    checkbox.parent().parent().removeClass('redBackground');
                }
            }

        });
</script>
```

Hopefully this makes sense... :)

Answer (score 1):

The code is a little to small to exactly get what your settings are.

From the fact that you have a  Element I deduce that you have multiple rows in a table. 
Personally I'd object to having a AjaxForm in each of the rows. That seems like a lot of overhead.

You could very easy have a single construct of jQuery code to handle all rows and perform the neccessary tasks by itself.

If you use the live function of jQuery you are even independent of rows being added.

The checkbox or the row need to have an identifier with which you can send the ajax call back to your controller. On success you can evaluate the state of the checkbox and color the row appropriately.

I would have to see more of the code, to really help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something. This seems like a job for html or css. As far as I can make out, there are several ways to approach this depending on your requirements.

On a row by row basis (i.e., you will never know what the colours are until they are defined somewhere by the app or in a database where storing their value statically is not an option), assign the html style property `<tr style='background-color: @Model.Colour'>` on the row to set the `background-color` to the colour you want.

On a type/state basis (i.e., you know what the colours are going to be ahead of time, but not what rows they are going to be assigned to), I'd define a class for each row: `<tr class='@Model.Type'>` and then assign the `background-color` in your CSS class with the same name as the value in Model.Type.

To get that colour/type itself, you are going to want to pass it in using your model. You might already have that property on your model, I don't know.

For simple alternating pattens, [simply use this technique](http://www.somacon.com/p338.php) or the `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` css selectors.

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best solutions.

Comment: I think you misunderstood his requirements...
He wants to set the background color of a row dependent on a value of the model.
The problem lies within the fact that the Model value can be changed via an Ajax call. 
I am not exactly sure if the Ajax form really does change the Model value, but rather does only set the value of the control within its form.

Comment: Yes, that is correct: the model gets updated with the checklist value, but that's not my main issue.  I could of simply used something like: <tr@(Model.ExampleItemComplete? " class=completeRow" : "")>, but because there isn't a page refresh (which is good- i don't want one), the user wouldn't see it.  So i need a jQuery-based solution ideally.

Comment: you probably do should do it like that first, so that it works irrespective of javascript. Then once that works successfully, load the value via ajax() and add or remove a class using JQuery's addClass() function targeting the same technique. Since you are posting the data, I'm guessing you already know which row you are interested in. If you don't directly, I'd suggest adding an id to the row to reference against.

Comment: To elaborate on Silent answer, I would suggest that you add the jquery function in your HideProcessingMsg to verify the checkbox value and assign the color accordingly